# Echo product attribute, only if it has value

Tags: product, php, attributes

I have this to display the attribute on my product page:

```
<?php echo "Bottle size: ", $_product->getAttributeText('bottle_size'); ?>
```

However, not all of my products will have this attribute so I don't want it to display anything if the "`bottle_size`" attribute has no value in it.

How can I achieve this?

---

**UPDATE:::::**

Tried this but that still doesn't work:

```
<?php
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute("bottle_size")->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
if ($attribute_value) {
echo $attribute_value
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **IF condition** to display if your Attribute contains value

```
<?php $attributeValue = $_product->getAttributeText('bottle_size'); ?>
<?php if(isset($attributeValue)): ?>
    <?php echo "Bottle size: ".$attributeValue; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That's something I am looking for, unfortunately it's not working for me :/  Hi Abhishek btw ;) you again!

Comment: Do you get attribute value in `$_product->getAttributeText('bottle_size')` .. like 500ML

Comment: Yes, `<?php echo "Bottle size: ", $_product->getAttributeText('bottle_size'); ?>` that works just fine.

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: Still nothing :/

Comment: Did you cleared the cache ?? check in Incognito window

Comment: Yes I did, and still nothing :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69387/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-bare-feet).

Comment: Glad that its working fine. and it was coming from cache

Comment: Ahhh, it looks like the condition is not working properly tho. The product where this value doesn't exists still displays the "Bottle size: "

Comment: Sorted again :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code this

```
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute("attribute_code")->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
if ($attribute_value != "") {
    echo $attribute_value;
}
```

Comment: don't seem to work... Look my updated question

Comment: Please try my updated answer. If it will not work then please let me know in detail what issue you are getting.

Comment: That didn't work either :/

Comment: What value getting in this variable $attribute_value?

Comment: This is my current code: `<?php 
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute("bottle_size")->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
if ($attribute_value != "") {
    echo $attribute_value;
} 
?>` The value of "bottle_size" should be `50ml`